# Vue-Loader: Assigning base-url for all required .vue components

Tags: webpack, vue.js, require, vue-loader

I am using vue-loader for an application. I want to decouple my components as much as possible and have a situation where I want to have a component like so:

**Test.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
  Testing My Vue
  <child></child>
</div>
```

```
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {}
  },
  beforeCreate(){
    var child  = require("./CompanyName/Components/child.vue");
    Vue.component("child",child);
  }
}
</script>
```

Notice the following line

```
var child  = require("./CompanyName/Components/child.vue");
```

**Child.vue**

```
<template>
 <div>This is my Child component</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {

    data () {
      return {};
    }
  }
</script>
```

Running "webpack" on my application causes the following error:

> ERROR in
>   ./~/babel-loader/lib!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/CompanyName.Module/Views/Test/test.vue
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory'
>   C:\Users\user1\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\CompanyName.Web.ClientSide\CompanyName.Module.Website\Scripts\src\CompanyName.Module\Views\TestCompanyName/Components/child.vue
>   in C:\Users\user1\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\CompanyName.Web.ClientSide\CompanyName.Module.Website\Scripts\src\CompanyName.Module\Views\Test
>   @
>   ./~/babel-loader/lib!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/CompanyName.Module/Views/Test/test.vue
>   23:16-70

It seems that the vue-loader is not recognizing './' as the base path of my application (ie 'src').
I want to have all my references start from the same folder so that I define them all at startup and perhaps add aliases.
 ***Is there a way to configure webpack.config so that it recognizes that './' means '/src' whenever it meets a dependency injected using require() ?***

*This used to be handled when using require.js in the old days*

```
//the old days
requirejs.config({
 baseUrl:'./src'
})
```

**My Webpack.config**

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {

    entry: "./src/main.js",
    output: {
        path: '../Dist',
        publicPath: '../Dist/',
        filename: 'build.js'
    },
    resolve: {
       alias: {
            'vue': 'vue/dist/vue.js',
       }

    },
    module: {
        rules: [
           {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',           
           }
        ],
        loaders: [
           {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue',
            }
        ]
     },
    devtool: "#source-map",
    vue: {
       loaders: {
           js: 'babel'
       }
   } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `@` alias in the `webpack.conf.js` file, like:

```
alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.js',
      '@': resolve('src')
    }
```

Then, in your include / require you could use the `@` to point directly to your vue/src folder:

```
include '@/components/Hello'  //This will point to ./src/components/Hello.vue
```

P.D = what you mean with `running webpack`? If you had installed the vue with `vue-cli` you should use `npm run dev` or `npm run prod` instead of `webpack`.

Hope it helps!